# Best way to implement PHP constants in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, model-view-controller, codeigniter

So I am using Codeignitor and I am trying to figure out the best way to share my constants with my javascript in a neat maintainable way.

1) in the view I could echo out my variables in like my footer (yuuuck!)
2) I could parse a partial view which contains a template for javascript and inject that in my view (maybe?)
3) I could dynamically create a javascript file like myJavascript.js.php and include that in my header.

What's the best maintainable way to implement PHP into JS in a MVC framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep my variables nicely wrapped I use a JSON object - that way I won't incur in issues with encoding, slashes, having to manually update the JavaScript every variable I add...

```
$variables_to_view['js_variables']['var_name'] = $var_name;
```

then pass it to the view

```
php_variables = <?php echo json_encode($js_variables) ?>;
alert(php_variables.var_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong about echoing your variables in the script tag. In fact, frameworks like BackboneJS are [encouraging](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-bootstrap) you to do so for data you need to pass to your client-side code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use short tag like this:

For Example:
You want to use $abc variable in js, then you will need to write this in js

```
var abc = <?=$abc?>;
```

Comment: Even regular php tags and echo would work...and it's option 1) in OP's question

Comment: that will work but I prefer this way as its more handy to use

Answer (score 1):

You can create php file .
Something like script.js.php?outfor=1;

```
 <?php
  header("Content-type:text/javascript"); //can be application/javascript.
 ?>

 ABC = <?php echo $abc?>
 CBA = <?php echo $cba?>
 BAC = <?php echo $bac?> //and so on.
```

Some additional info .
If you use "var" in function that variable will be visible only in that function  and without "var"means global.

So.

```
function abc() 
{
  var a = 1; //only in abc()
  b=2;  //global
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that in terms of programming skills it's not the best, but finally it's what I use and it's working. To make it short: I put all my constants in a xml file and I have this little script that generates two separate files with the same content, but different syntax. I am just pasting the code with my values. If it's useful for anybody, I'll be very happy to help.
The xml is the simplest possible; value

```
<?php
define("GECOXML_PATH","../xml/geco.xml");
define("PHP_GECO_FN","../.includes/geco.php");
define("JS_GECO_FN","../js/geco.js");
echo "********   GECO (GEnerate COnstants files for PHP and JS) **********<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "         input xml file: ". GECOXML_PATH."<br>";
echo "         output php file: ". PHP_GECO_FN."<br>";
echo "         output js file: ". JS_GECO_FN."<br>";
echo "********************************************************************<br>";

$geco = (object)xmlParse(GECOXML_PATH);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "************ PHP GECO ************* <br>";
echo "<br>";
$PHP =  gecoPHP($geco);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "************** JS GECO ************<br>";
echo "<br>";
$JS = gecoJS($geco);
writeFiles($PHP, $JS);

//****** Functions *********

function xmlParse ($url) {
        $fileContents= file_get_contents($url);
        $fileContents = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $fileContents);
        $fileContents = trim(str_replace('"', "'", $fileContents));
        return simplexml_load_string($fileContents);
    }

function writeFiles($PHPcontent, $JScontent)
{
            echo "<br> PhP ok:". file_put_contents(PHP_GECO_FN, $PHPcontent)  . "<br>";
            echo "<br> JS ok:" . file_put_contents(JS_GECO_FN, $JScontent) . "<br>";
}

function gecoPHP($gecoOBJ)
{
    foreach ($gecoOBJ as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_numeric(str_replace(" ","",$value)))
            {
                $line = "define(\"" . $key . "\",". intval($value) .  ");\n";
            }
            else
            {
                $line = "define(\"" . $key . "\",\"". $value .  "\");\n";
            }
        $phpContent = $phpContent . $line;
     echo $line."<br>";
    }
   return "<?php\n"$phpContent."?>";
}

function gecoJS($gecoOBJ)
{
    foreach ($gecoOBJ as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_numeric(str_replace(" ","",$value)))
            {
                $line = "var " . $key . "=". $value . ";\n";
            }
            else
            {
                $line = "var " . $key . "=\"". $value . "\";\n";
            }
        $JSContent =  $JSContent . $line;
    echo $line."<br>";
    }
   return $JSContent;
}
?>
```

Comment: Something whent wrong when formatting: So xml: <key><value></key>